# Perforce API - Get revision/changelist number

Tags: c#, perforce

I'm trying to write a C# program to automate some stuff in perforce.
I want to get the revision/changelist number because I want to pass this number to a variable I will use later in the code (are they the same thing? I'm talking about the number on the first column on the following image):

[image].

What's the API call I should do to get this number?

I have tried digging through the API documentation but I couldn't find anything...
This is my current code if it's going to help:

```
string CredentialsJSON = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(PathToP4Credentials);

P4Credentials = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<P4Credentials>(CredentialsJSON);

// Assume this means we'll need to submit the update.

string uri = P4Credentials.ServerUri;
string user = P4Credentials.P4User;
string ws_client = P4Credentials.P4Client;
string pass = P4Credentials.P4Password;

// define the server, repository and connection
Server server = new Server(new ServerAddress(uri));
Repository rep = new Repository(server);con = rep.Connection;

// use the connection variables for this connection
con.UserName = user;
con.Client = new Client();
con.Client.Name = ws_client;

 // connect to the server
con.Connect(null);

Options LoginOptions = new Options();
Credential cred = con.Login(pass, LoginOptions, user);
FileSpec DefaultGameFileSpec = new FileSpec(null, null, new LocalPath(PathToDefaultGameINI), null);

if (DefaultGameFileSpec.Version.Equals(null))
{
versionspec = "Null";
}
else
{
versionspec = DefaultGameFileSpec.Version.ToString();
}
                    
// First, ensure the local file is sync'ed
Options SyncOptions = new SyncFilesCmdOptions(SyncFilesCmdFlags.None);
con.Client.SyncFiles(SyncOptions, DefaultGameFileSpec);
                    
// At this point, you really should resolve.  There may have been local edits!

Options EditOptions = new Options();
con.Client.EditFiles(EditOptions, DefaultGameFileSpec);
bNeedToSubmit = true;
```

Comment: I recommend experimenting with the `p4 changes` command at the command line.  It's not clear to me WHICH changelist you might be trying to find in your code, but if you mess around with that command you'll probably be able to figure out what server command gets you what you're looking for, and then translate that to a C# API call.